# How to download multiple files into a folder in webix?

Tags: download, blob, webix

I am trying to download two text files by the 'Download_Files' button.

I am facing below problems :

1. In the getFiles() function, if I comment out the webix.message, only the second file is getting saved. How can I save both the files into that function without the webix.message?
2. Is it possible to download them into a folder ?

Snippet is here : https://snippet.webix.com/a0qpcpxx

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) 
Your code works correctly for me. Still, you can try to make some delay between two downloads

```
webix.html.download(blob1, "file1.txt");
setTimeout(function(){
    webix.html.download(blob2, "file2.txt");
}, 100);
```

(2) 
There is no way to control the target folder for downloaded files

That is default browser behavior, files always are downloaded into the "Downloads" folder or into folder selected by the user

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful!

Comment: I have a slightly different question on this same problem. In this link https://snippet.webix.com/q8gw1xvz I am trying to download 3 files with delay and every time I am using the blob object with name as  'var blob' . I notice that with this naming the 3rd and 2nd file are generating with same content. If I change the names to blob2 and blob3 , then they are getting generated with appropriate content. Why it is happening although I am creating the var blob variable under different block and locally ?

Comment: That is way how javascript works, while you are using var 3 times, javascript will create a single variable for it, which will cause the problem

You can use "let" instead of "var", works in modern browsers only, though. Or use different variable naming.

https://snippet.webix.com/1ktsezhb